# Using i-frame or SDK to embed Google meets

Tags: angular, typescript, sdk, google-meet

Is there a way in which I can embed Google meets in my `angular 12` web-app using `i-frame` or their `SDK`(if they provide).

On trying to open a Google meet meeting in an i-frame I receive the see below error message. I haven't discovered any proper documentation for integrating a SDK for Google meets.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="url1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <button (click)="onSubmit()" class="primary">GO</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <iframe [src]="url" allow="microphone; camera;fullscreen" 
        width="1000px" height="1000px"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Typescript code:

```
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, public ds: DomSanitizer) {}
    url: SafeResourceUrl;
    url1: string;
    onSubmit() {
        this.url = this.ds.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url1);
        console.log(this.url);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Google API's does not currently have an SDK for Google Meets, meaning integrating google meetings into an application is currently not possible.

- See thread discussion on this [here](https://support.google.com/meet/thread/63731528/do-we-have-google-meet-api-sdk-so-that-we-can-integrate-it-into-our-website-mobile-app?hl=en).
- See their available [API library](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?project=elegant-poetry-142423&pli=1).

[image]

Comment: fyi, there is a feature request on Google's issue tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289696532

Comment: Yes and there you can also upvote the ticket to get more eyes on it